# Intro to Java Programming Currency Converter input

Tags: java, input, output, currency

I'm so out of my depth in this class. It's supposed to be a basic currency converter. I highlighted where I'm having trouble in both the example & my own code. I need advice on collecting the input & outputting the input depending on what my input is (if that makes sense). My code is below, it's still in the beginning stages.

The output of the program should look like this below:

```
(Example) Welcome to the Currency Converter Program (Example)

Use the following codes to input your currency choices:
    1 – US Dollars
    2 – Euros 
    3 – British Pounds
    4 – Japanese Yen

Please choose the input currency: 2

Now choose the output currency: 1

Now enter the input in *Euros*: €10.00 <--- *This is where I am stuck at right now. How
can I get the output to say Euro's, dollars, yen, etc. depending on what my input 
currency is?*


€10.00 Euros at a conversion rate of 1.5 Euros to Dollars = $15.00 US Dollars.


Thank you for using the Currency Converter Program!


===========================================================
```

public class currency
{

```
 public currency()
{
    char us_dollar_sym = 36;
    char pound_sym = 163;
    char yen_sym = 165;
    char euro_sym = 8364; 

    double us_dollar = 0; 
    double pound = 0;
    double yen = 0;
    double euro =0;

    // Interface
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Currency Converter Program \n");
    System.out.println("Use the following codes to input your currency choices: \n 1 - US dollars \n 2 - Euros \n 3 - British Pounds \n 4 - Japanese Yen \n");

    // Collect user input
    System.out.println("Please choose the input currency:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = in.next(); 

    System.out.println("Please choose the output currency");
    String output = in.next();

    System.out.printf("Now enter the input in"); <-- Stuck here 
    double input = in.nextInt(); 



}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `switch` statement.

```
System.out.println("Please choose the input currency:");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String choice = in.next(); 

String inType;
switch(choice) {
    case "1":
        inType = "US Dollars";
        break;
    // etc...
    default:
        inType = null;
        System.out.println("Please enter a correct currency type from the list.");
}

System.out.printf("Now enter the input in" + inType);
```

Comment: On the default case, inType should be changed to null. The compiler won't let you compile as-is because inType might never be initialized. Edited.